# inputSearchValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I recently started React and I don't understand why it tells me that the inputSearchValue function is not a function.

The inputSearchValue function is used to retrieve the value entered by the user, to create a search bar.

Here is my code:

App/index.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import repos from 'src/data/repos';

import './style.scss';

import SearchBar from 'src/components/SearchBar';
import Message from 'src/components/Message';
import ReposResults from 'src/components/ReposResults';

const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(repos.items);

  const [searchedValue, setSearchedValue] = useState('');

  const countResults = () => {
    const reposResults = posts.filter((post) => post);
    return reposResults.length;
  };

  const inputSearchValue = (inputValue) => {
    setSearchedValue(inputValue);
  };

  const numberOfResults = countResults(posts);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <SearchBar
        searchedValue={searchedValue}
        listOfPosts={posts}
        changeSearchValue={inputSearchValue}
      />
      <Message counter={numberOfResults} />
      <ReposResults repos={posts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

SearchBar/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import img from 'src/assets/images/logo-github.png';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import './style.scss';

const SearchBar = ({ searchedValue, inputSearchValue }) => (
  <div className="searchbar">
    <img src={img} alt="logo-githug" className="searchbar-img" />
    <Segment className="searchbar-segment">
      <Input
        icon="search"
        placeholder="Chercher un repos"
        iconPosition="left"
        className="searchbar-input"
        value={searchedValue}
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          inputSearchValue(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </Segment>
  </div>
);

SearchBar.propTypes = {
  searchedValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  inputSearchValue: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default SearchBar;
```

In the const SearchBar, I used an onChange event with a function that returns the current entry.

When I place an onSubmit event, I cannot write in the input

Comment: You named the prop differently `changeSearchValue={inputSearchValue}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update props name

```
<SearchBar
  searchedValue={searchedValue}
  listOfPosts={posts}
  inputSearchValue={inputSearchValue}  //need to update props name
/>
```

Comment: This question is unlikely to help future readers as it is more of a "typo" problem, and should be voted to be closed. Not all questions are worth answering.